# ParseExact FormatExecption

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

This

```
DateTime EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact("24/07/2015 12:00 AM", "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

generates

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

And I cannot seem to find the problem.

Comment: Use `dd/MM/yyyy` for the `date` portion. I.e. `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt`. See: [MSDN Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). The `DD` and `YYYY` format specifiers are illegal in .NET.

Comment: you cant make up your own format codes

Comment: Why do you set the CultureInfo to us-US, That string is not a us-US date

Comment: @Steve That is definitely an `en-US` date. I haven't the foggiest of what you're referring to. I just ran it and it passed without issue, after I fixed the format specifier of course. The only thing the `IFormatProvider provider` does is make sure the literals are correct. (`AM`/`PM`, week-day literals, etc.) (Source: [MSDN DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @EBrown an `en-US` date would be `07/24/2015 12:00 AM` with the months and the days swapped.

Comment: @phuzi Then *what exactly* is the `string format` parameter for? Please explain. (That's a rhetorical question, your comment is entirely wrong. The `string format` method defines what format the date is in, the culture info defines how strings are processed within it. I.e. `MMM`, etc.) Also, various areas of the US use different dates. I write them as `d MMM yyyy` for Military Compatibility.

Comment: It works like this, but to play safe I changed it to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: @EBrown I was only noticing an inconsistency in the OP question, Usually (and I am the least qualified to say that) the _short pattern_ for an en-US date is _M/d/yyyy_ and I was puzzled because the parser worked fine with the supplied string. However you have a point with The only thing the IFormatProvider provider does is make sure the literals are correct but can you point me exactly where this is written in the link on MSDN?

Comment: @Steve The link I posted above to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx). "The particular date and time symbols and strings (such as names of the days of the week in a particular language) used in s are defined by the provider parameter."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
DateTime EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact("24/07/2015 12:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The problem is that the specified format didn't match the format of the string you passed.

Comment: Thank you veru much, that worked. Sadly I cannot up vote.

Comment: @EgeAydın you welcome dude. I am glad that I helped. Not a problem

Comment: I got enough reputation to upvote, finally and that's what i just did. :)